# java web application deployed to google app engine using maven,deployment successful,but for all back end services getting 404 error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, paas

am trying to deploy my java/spring based web application to google app engine using maven following below steps
1) In pom.xml added appengine-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
       <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.42</version>
       <configuration>
              <version>1</version>
              <oauth2>false</oauth2>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

2) added appengine-web.xml

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>XXX-XXX-14807</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <env-variables>
    <env-var name="env" value="prod" />
  </env-variables>
</appengine-web-app>
```

3) deployed application using **mvn appengine:update** command
the application deployed successfully,welcome page getting displayed,but
services failing throwing errors like 
"The requested URL XXX-XXX-14807.appspot.com/serach.do was not found on the server"(working in my local tomcat).
PS: not used google app engine eclipse plugin for deployment, trying to deploy java project from maven followed https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp. 
do we need any other configuration?

Comment: Hi, have you sorted that out ? I don't have the <application> and <version> in my appengine-web.xml file but keep both in pom.xml within the plugin in configuration tag.